# Enabling a button when a form has a valid state in blazor server application

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I am working on a page where I want to be able to enable a button when the state of a form is valid.

Here is my html

```
         <EditForm EditContext="@EditContext">    
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />     
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name: </label>

                <InputText Id="name"  @bind-Value="@Model.Name"    @onkeyup='@(e=>KeyboardEventHandler(e,"Name"))' />
               
            </div>    
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="body">Text: </label>

                <InputText Id="body"  @bind-Value="@Model.Text"   @onkeyup='@(e=>KeyboardEventHandler(e,"Text"))' />

            </div>    
            <button type="submit" disabled="@OkayDisabled">Ok</button> 
            
        </EditForm>
```

Here is my c# code.

```
         public partial class Index : ComponentBase
            {
                private EditContext EditContext;
                protected string OkayDisabled { get; set; } = "disabled";
                private string StatusMessage;
                private string StatusClass;

                string KeyPressed = "";
                string EventInfo = "";

                private GuestbookEntry Model = new GuestbookEntry();

                protected override void OnInitialized()
                {
                    EditContext = new EditContext(Model);
                    EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
                }

                protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
                {
                    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);

                    //if (firstRender)
                    //{

                    //}

                    SetOkDisabledStatus();
                }

                private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    SetOkDisabledStatus();
                }

                private void SetOkDisabledStatus()
                {
                    if (EditContext.Validate())
                    {
                        OkayDisabled = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OkayDisabled = "disabled";
                    }
                }


                private void KeyboardEventHandler(KeyboardEventArgs e, string memberName)
                {
                    var property = Model.GetType().GetProperty(memberName);
                    var value = property.GetValue(Model);
                    property.SetValue(Model, value + e.Key);

                    var id = EditContext.Field(memberName);
                    EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(id);
                }

            }
```

Anytime I type in the two input boxes the Okay button is enabled which is good. If I decide to clear the two input boxes all the keys
that I press on the keyboard begins to get captured in the input controls. Example, I press backspace and backspace is stored in the input
control.

```
What am I doing wrong?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @onkeyup catches everything from the keyboard including nonprintable characters.

While the @onkeypress only captures printable characters, and
changing to @onkeypress should resolve your issue.

Edit (code for comment):

```
<EditForm EditContext="this.editContext">
    <InputTextOnInput @bind-Value="this.temp.Prop1"/>
    <InputTextOnInput @bind-Value="this.temp.Prop2"/>
    <button disabled="@((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temp.Prop1) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temp.Prop2)))" @onclick="@(this.someClickAction)">Click me</button>
</EditForm>



@code {
    private EditContext editContext;
    private TempClass temp = new();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.editContext = new EditContext(temp);
    }

    private class TempClass
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code from InputTextOnInput:

```
@* Inherits from the original InputText component *@
@inherits InputText
@* Bind the oninput event *@
<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
   class="@CssClass"
   value="@CurrentValue"
   @oninput="EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString)" />
```

*Note: InputTextOnInput taken from: [Gérald Barré](https://www.meziantou.net/validating-an-input-on-keypress-instead-of-on-change-in-blazor.htm)*

Comment: The @onKeypress works now but when I clear either of the input boxes the ok button should be disable again but it is not getting disabled.

Comment: That would be because it's not refreshing due to the method only being called on printable characters. The two solutions I can think of is use the @onkeyup and use regex to make sure it is a valid character, or set the disabled property based on if either of those values you are binding to are null / white space.
If you switch it back to @ onkeyup instead of using regex just check your two model fields if either are null/whitespace if they are not then activate the button and do the rest of the behavior else disable button and return.

Comment: @Baba Adding some code to my answer in one moment.

Comment: This does not work. All I get is this error. Multiple components use the tag 'InputTextOnInput'. 
Components: BlazorFormValidation.Pages.InputTextOnInput, BlazorFormValidation.Pages.InputTextOnInput, 
BlazorFormValidation.Shared.InputTextOnInput, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Bind BlazorFormValidation

Comment: Did you include the InputTextOnInput as a different .razor file named the same way you with to call it? and is that path being included on the page you are trying to use it? When is this error happening (Typing in it, trying to compile it)?
Can you copy and paste the InputTextOnInput you are using. I believe it's because you have multiple @bind on it/

Comment: I think I screwed up. I had two copies in the solution and now it is okay.